# Convert char yyyy-mm-dd to num ddmmyy10

Tags: sas

My char date var is YYYY-MM-DD and I would like to convert it to numeric date var ddmmyy10.

I tried:

```
Num_date=PUT(char_date,yymmdd10.);
Format num_date ddmmyy10.;
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR 48-59: The format $YYMMDD was not found or could not be loaded.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `input`:

```
data want;
    char_date='2023-10-26';
    Num_date=input(char_date,yymmdd10.);
    Format num_date ddmmyy10.;
run;
```

How I remember it:

**in**put turns a character **in**to a number